# Help finding value of x in logarithms?

Tags: logarithms

How to find the value of x in:

$$10=8.4\log(0.3x+1)$$

so far I got :

$$10=\log(0.3x+1)^{8.4}$$

$$10^{10}=(0.3x+1)^{8.4}$$

What should I do next?

Comment: Raise both sides to the power $1/8.4$.

Comment: Presumably you $\log$ is base $10$?

Comment: Here is a hint: Start with $$10=8.4\log(0.3x+1).$$ Divide both sides by $8.4$ too get $$\frac{10}{8.4}=\log(0.3x+1).$$ Then use the fact that $$10^{log(Y)}=Y$$ for $Y>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

${10 \over 8.4} = \log (0.3 x +1 )$.

$10^{10 \over 8.4} = 0.3 x +1$.

${ 10^{10 \over 8.4} -1 \over 0.3} = x$.

Answer (score 0):

Our equation:
$$10=8.4\log(0.3x+1)$$
Divide $8.4$ on both sides
$$\dfrac{10}{8.4}=\log(0.3x+1)$$
$$\dfrac{100}{84}=\log(0.3x+1)$$
$$\dfrac{25}{22}=\log(0.3x+1)$$
Remember that if $\log_a(b)=x$, then $a^x=b$.
$$\dfrac{25}{22}=\log_{10}(0.3x+1)$$
$$10^{25/22}=0.3x+1$$
$$\sqrt[22]{10^{25}}=0.3x+1$$
$$0.3x=\sqrt[22]{10^{25}}-1$$
$$\dfrac{3}{10}x=\sqrt[22]{10^{25}}-1$$
$$x=\dfrac{\sqrt[22]{10^{25}}-1}{\left(\dfrac{3}{10}\right)}$$
$$\displaystyle \boxed{x=\dfrac{10\sqrt[22]{10^{25}}-1}{3}}$$